# Where are the docs for solid-pop3?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postfix, pop3

I'm trying to install solid-pop3d on an Ubuntu server, but I am having a very hard time finding anything online by way of documentation. I've heard that the project is very active, yet there does not seem to be much available. I can't find any documentation outside of the spare man page, and I'm trying to figure out what the expected format is for the 'virtuals file' which is referenced several times (I'm trying to set up virtual users on the machine).

The reason I'm trying solid-pop3 is because I ran into problems with Dovecot and I'm tired of it. Is there a better pop3 daemon option? I just need something simple that stays alive.

Someone please tag this with 'spop3' and 'solid-pop3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by *I am having a very hard time finding anything online by way of documentation*?

1. Here is the [Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/solid-pop3d.8.html) for 12.04.
2. This is the man page for [The Solid Pop3 Server](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/dot-spop3d.5.html).
3. and this is the Man page for [the Solid Pop3 configuration file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/spop3d.conf.5.html)
4. This is the Google cache of the [polarsys.ca Web page with instructions for Solid Pop3](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PNgHgH4-QBsJ:www.polarsys.ca/docs/linuxdocs/qmail/solid.html%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu-browser).
5. This is the Man page for [spdbm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/45/idpl/19493469/numer/8/nazwa/spdbm), a Solid Pop3 database management utility.

I hope you will find here enough material to make it work.

Comment: thanks, I think spdbm was the missing piece of the puzzle for me